# Recorrer un json desde un controlador de laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

tengo un fichero "blade" que me genera un JSON y lo envia mediante POST a un controlador para guardar los datos.

Un ejemplo del Json es este

[image]

La petición post, la hago de esta forma

```
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{{ route('front.user.formElements.create') }}",
            data: {
                {{--"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",--}}
                data : formBuilder.actions.getData()
            },
            statusCode: {
                200: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                },
                400: function (response) {
                    alert('error 400');
                },
            },
            error: function(data) {


            }
        });
```

El código que tengo "empezado" para el controlador seria esto, pero $request->get('data') no recibo nada, pensaba que aquí estaría la info que envio desde el formulario.

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    $data_from_form = $request->get('data');

    return response()->json($data_from_form, 200);
}
```

Comment: Por qué no agregas `dataType:"json"` y además, `JSON.stringify(formBuilder.actions.getData())`?

Comment: Gracias @L.Flor, solucionado. 1000 gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para enviar un `json` mediante `ajax`, debes hacerlo como un string, utilizando [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify). Además, es recomendable especificar el tipo de dato que viaja. Por tanto, tu petición ajax debería quedar así:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{{ route('front.user.formElements.create') }}",
        data: {
            {{--"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",--}}
            data : JSON.stringify(formBuilder.actions.getData())
        },
        dataType: "json",
        statusCode: {
            200: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            400: function (response) {
                alert('error 400');
            },
        },
        error: function(data) {


        }
    });
```

Además, no olvides que en tu servidor recibirás un string, por tanto, debes convertir ese string a json.

Comment: Muchas gracias, así lo he hecho.